# Publishing service using service definition file (sd) through the ArcGIS REST API?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, rest

The algorithm I have so far is basically this:

1. Create a `sddraft` from a `mxd` file (using [arcpy.CreateMapSDDraft()](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/createmapsddraft.htm).
2. Stage `sddraft` into a `sd` file (using [arcpy.StageService_server()](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/server/stage-service.htm).
3. Upload `sd` file to ArcGIS server over REST.

   1. There's a little dance that has to happen due to the fact that we use `web-adaptor` and have to redirect all requests to a single-sign-on server first for authentication, before forwarding the *intended* request to the *intended* destination.
4. Call `createService` on ArcGIS server's REST API, pointing to the uploaded `sd` file.

   1. This happens in the same http session, so no need to go through the authentication dance again.

The fourth step manages to create the service, but startup fails due to `Invalid file`. The only documentation for the `createService` endpoint that I could find is [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/enterprise-administration/server/createservice.htm), and I can only surmise that the endpoint only accepts the old and deprecated `msd` file, but not the newer `sd` file. If that's the case, what endpoint am I supposed to hit for creating a service from a `sd` file? Note that [arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition()](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/server/upload-service-definition.htm) isn't an option for us due to the fact that authentication is handled elsewhere from the ArcGIS server.

Comment: What does `CanCreateService` return?

Comment: Status code 500: ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Finally* got a working solution.

First off, if you're using a webadaptor front-end, the base URI that you'll be using will likely be something like: `https://<your-domain>/web-adaptor`

So paths to endpoints as defined in the official documentation will be relative to that base URI, e.g. the absolute path to the file upload endpoint would be `https://<your-domain>/web-adaptor/admin/uploads/upload`.

Now that's out of the way, here's the algorithm for publishing a service (you'll need an `http` library like the python [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/2.7.0/) module that also allows you to make calls in a single session).

(all calls here are assumed to be made with a given session object)

1. Make your authentication calls with whatever your SSO solution is.
2. Upload your service definition file in  POST request to `/admin/uploads/upload`, with a parameter `{"f": "json"}`. You'll receive the ID that the server generates for the file in the response as `itemID`.
3. The ArcGIS Server will create a service configuration file for your service definition. Grab it by making a GET request to `/admin/uploads/<itemID>/serviceconfiguration.json?f=json`.
4. Start a job to create the service by making  POST request to `/rest/services/System/PublishingTools/GPServer/Publish%20Service%20Definition/submitJob`, passing the ff. JSON object in the body:

```
{

  "in_sdp_id": <itemID>,

  "in_config_overwrite": <the content of the serviceconfiguration.json from step 3>,

  "f": "json"

}
```

You'll receive the `jobID` in the response.

You can repeatedly make a GET request to `/rest/services/System/PublishingTools/GPServer/Publish Service Definition/jobs/<jobID>?f=json` to check the status if your job. You'll know it's done once `jobStatus` is set to `esriJobSucceeded`. The URL to your service will also be available in the `results.out_rest_svc_url.paramUrl` property.

Comment: could you post some of your python code? I am having a hard time getting the requests/session to work...

Comment: I had to add a `Referer` header = `https://FQDN:6443/arcgis/tokens/generateToken` on the request to `arcgis/rest/services/System/PublishingTools/GPServer/Publish Service Definition/submitJob`

Comment: Yeah, that approach is needed if authenticating directly with a site-admin user is available to you. In our case, we run our automation on a separate network, so we have to use the public interface (web-adaptor) and our SSO service.